# What is the frequency of Devanagari signs in Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit, frequency, devanagari

I've been searching everywhere to find the frequency of Devanagari's signs (including the sign in a conjunct) in a typical Sanskrit text. I found the frequency of Devanagari conjuncts [here](http://www.sanskritweb.net/deutsch/devanagari.pdf) and there are a million sites on the word frequency of Sanskrit but no luck for particular signs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, the very same source (Whitney's grammar) used in your conjunct consonants link also gives the frequencies of individual phonemes, which I will take to be an acceptable proxy for non-conjunct glyphs. If you are really interested in the frequency of non-conjunct glyphs but not the phonemes, then I can't help, sorry.

[Here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=RFAIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA25&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false) is the relevant page.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me out.